# Set table width to \columnwidth

Tags: formatting, latex, tabular

I'm writing a report using the IEEEtran format, so my page is divided into two columns.

I want to insert a table inline and I want the items in their columns to be centered. There are a few similar posts and I have looked at documentation for `tabular*` and `tabularx`, but I could not make anything work. I have achieved the best result with the following.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse nec tincidunt justo. Fusce imperdiet tincidunt mauris, a hendrerit justo ultrices sodales. In at mi sit amet leo aliquam dignissim. Mauris fringilla fermentum egestas. Nulla facilisi. Nulla rutrum suscipit lectus vehicula consequat. Praesent eu sem vulputate, tristique augue et, cursus risus. Fusce sodales purus turpis, placerat interdum libero consequat at. Vestibulum convallis tincidunt lobortis. In ornare velit erat.

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{cccc}
\hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Frequency (Hz)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Manual Measurements} & Bode Analyzer\\
    \cline{2-3}
    \cline{4}
    & Linear Gain (V/V) & Logarithmic Gain (dB) & Logarithmic Gain (dB)\\
    \hline
    1000 & 0.04395 & -33.179 & -35\\
    2000 & 0.02274 & -38.902 & -42\\
    3000 & 0.01553 & -42.215 & -45\\
    4000 & 0.01185 & -44.564 & -47\\
    5000 & 0.00474 & -46.484 & -50\\
    \hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse nec tincidunt justo. Fusce imperdiet tincidunt mauris, a hendrerit justo ultrices sodales. In at mi sit amet leo aliquam dignissim. Mauris fringilla fermentum egestas. Nulla facilisi. Nulla rutrum suscipit lectus vehicula consequat. Praesent eu sem vulputate, tristique augue et, cursus risus. Fusce sodales purus turpis, placerat interdum libero consequat at. Vestibulum convallis tincidunt lobortis. In ornare velit erat.

\end{document}
```

[image: Here is what the table looks like]

I have tried using `p{measure}` instead of `c` to define the columns, but I can't get the text centered.

I have tried using tabularx, but I don't want all the columns to be the same width, and I don't want to fiddle with determining the relative widths of the columns.

I don't know if it was clear enough, but I absolutely do not mind if text spans multiple rows.

Comment: please make a compilable [mre] including the necessary packages and document class.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach with the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse nec tincidunt justo. Fusce imperdiet tincidunt mauris, a hendrerit justo ultrices sodales. In at mi sit amet leo aliquam dignissim. Mauris fringilla fermentum egestas. Nulla facilisi. Nulla rutrum suscipit lectus vehicula consequat. Praesent eu sem vulputate, tristique augue et, cursus risus. Fusce sodales purus turpis, placerat interdum libero consequat at. Vestibulum convallis tincidunt lobortis. In ornare velit erat.

\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{columns={halign=c},rows={valign=m}, row{3-7}={mode=math},colspec={@{}XXXX@{}}}
    \hline
    \SetCell[r=2]{} Frequency (Hz) & \SetCell[c=2]{} Manual Measurements & & Bode Analyzer\\
    \hline
    & Linear Gain (V/V) & Logarithmic Gain (dB) & Logarithmic Gain (dB)\\
    \hline
    1000 & 0.04395 & -33.179 & -35\\
    2000 & 0.02274 & -38.902 & -42\\
    3000 & 0.01553 & -42.215 & -45\\
    4000 & 0.01185 & -44.564 & -47\\
    5000 & 0.00474 & -46.484 & -50\\
    \hline
\end{tblr}
\end{center}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse nec tincidunt justo. Fusce imperdiet tincidunt mauris, a hendrerit justo ultrices sodales. In at mi sit amet leo aliquam dignissim. Mauris fringilla fermentum egestas. Nulla facilisi. Nulla rutrum suscipit lectus vehicula consequat. Praesent eu sem vulputate, tristique augue et, cursus risus. Fusce sodales purus turpis, placerat interdum libero consequat at. Vestibulum convallis tincidunt lobortis. In ornare velit erat.

\end{document}
```

[image]